# How do I get full GROUP_CONCAT list on results with WHERE statement?

Tags: mysql

Here an example my database structure..

```
uid  email            name
-------------------------------
1    john@gmail.com   John
2    peter@gmail.com  Peter
3    colin@gmail.com  Colin
```

book table

```
book_id  book_name
-------------------
1        PHP
2        MySQL
3        Javascripts
4        CSS
```

history table

```
history_uid  history_bookid
---------------------------
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            1
2            3
3            3
```

Current statement including multi select query on `history.history_bookid`

```
SELECT users.uid,
       users.email,
       users.`name`,
       history.history_uid,
       history.history_bookid,
       GROUP_CONCAT(history.history_bookid) AS BookID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(book_name)              AS bookTitles
FROM   users
       INNER JOIN history
         ON users.uid = history.history_uid
       INNER JOIN book
         ON history.history_bookid = book.book_id
WHERE  history.history_bookid = 1
        OR history.history_bookid = 3
GROUP  BY users.uid
```

The results

```
uid email            name   history_uid  history_bookid  BookID   bookTitles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   john@gmail.com   John   1            3               3,1      Javascripts,PHP
2   peter@gmail.com  Peter  2            1               1,3      PHP,Javascripts
3   colin@gmail.com  Colin  3            3               3        Javascripts
```

**Question :**

How do I get full list of books was read by `uid = 1`? Example output I want is including all book in `history table`

```
uid email            name   history_uid  history_bookid  BookID   bookTitles
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   john@gmail.com   John   1            3               1,2,3    PHP,MySQL,Javascripts
2   peter@gmail.com  Peter  2            1               1,3      PHP,Javascripts
3   colin@gmail.com  Colin  3            3               3        Javascripts
```

Comment: Why do you have the filter in your `WHERE` clause, if you want every result?

Comment: @eggyal I used Chosen jQuery : Example http://i.stack.imgur.com/AWRYH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get full list of books was read by `uid = 1`?

Add that as a filter option to your `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE history.history_bookid IN (1,3) OR users.uid = 1
```

Comment: I have tried `IN` & `FIND_IN_SET` and results still same as `AND`. Something wrong I missed here?

Comment: @user1286499: My answer was referring more to the `OR users.uid = 1` part.

Comment: When you referring to the `uid` & it worked. I got an egg!. Actually the correct statement is `WHERE  history.history_uid = 1 OR history.history_uid = 3`

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want the titles as well as the book ids?

Add a `GROUP_CONCAT(book_name) AS bookTitles` to your field list.